# Ember.js {{action}} in {{each}}

Tags: ember.js

Say I have the following template

```
{{#each item in controller}}
    <a {{action "doSomething" item}}>{{item.name}}</a>
{{/each}}
```

Now I have the following action defined in the router.

```
doSomething: function(router, event){
    event.context.get('name');
}
```

is there anything wrong with accessing the property this way?
I'm just asking because I haven't seen this anywhere else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing at all wrong with doing that. That's the purpose of the context.